# Bernoulli trials and permutations

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

While solving questions using the Binomial probability theorem, the result is the probability of r successes among n trials, given that there are only two outcomes of probability p and q where p represent success(occurrence of desired event) and q represents failure(nonoccurrence of desired event), yes?

My doubt is this; does this theorem take into account **all** the different possibilities? For example, if I were applying this theorem to the situation of a family having three children:

If p is the probability of success of the birth of one boy, p=1/2 and q=1/2. Can we obtain the probability of 1 boy and 2 girls by

$³C1$x$(1/2)²$x$1/2=3/8?$ Does this account for all the permutations, viz. BBG, BGB and GBB? I am confused because we have used nCr here and not nPr.

Please share your insights and help me to understand this. Much thanks in advance :) Regards.

Comment: Note that 2 boys out of 3 is $\binom{3}{2}$, but since $\binom{3}{1}=\binom{3}{2}$, your equation is correct.

Comment: I have edited the question. It was s'posed to be 2 girls and 1 boy. Sorry.

Comment: My comment still holds

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution is a distribution of a sum of $n$ iid random variables with the Bernoulli distribution, i.e. if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid random variables with the Bernoulli distribution, then
$$
S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n
$$
has the binomial distribution. The random variable $S_n$ counts the number of success. The order is not important, only the number of success is important.

If we want to calculate the probability that we obtain $k$ successes out of $n$ trials, we first have to find the number of ways we can obtain $k$ successes. This is given by the binomial coefficient
$$
{n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$$
The probability to obtain $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures in any particular order is given by
$$
p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$
If we combine the number of ways we can obtain $k$ success with the probability, we get
$$
P(S_n=k)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
for $k\ge0$.

We took into account all different possibilities since we multiplied by the number of ways we can obtain $k$ successes. If $n=3$ and $k=2$, then there are $3$ ways to obtain $2$ successes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "$n$ iid random variables"? And I also don't understand how the number of ways to obtain $k$ successes out of $n$ trials is the binomial coefficient. If you could please explain that too?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar $n$ independent and identically distributed random variables. We repeat the same experiment independently $n$ times and count how many success we obtain.

Comment: Um, I'm so sorry but I still don't quite understand. Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar Could you be more specific? What part needs more explanation? By the binomial probabiltiy theorem, you mean the probability
$$
\binom n k  p^k(1-p)^{n-k},
$$
right? We use combinations here because the elements are indistinguishable (we cannot distinguish between two successes or two failures). Sometimes ${n\choose k}$ is denoted by ${}_nC_k$.

Comment: OK, never mind :) I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here when we calculate P(2 Girls and 1 boy) using Combination nCr, as we donot care about the order in which the children are born.
If we had used nPr, we are actually considering all possible orders(BGG, GGB, GBG..), which is not needed, so while using nCr we are actually considering combination of 1 Boy and 2 Girls.

P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B|A)
P(2 Girls and 1 Boy) = P(2 Girls) * P(1 boy| 2 Girls were born)

P(2 Girls) = Number of ways in which 2 girls are born out of 3 children(in any order) * P(Girl being born)^r * P(Boy being born)^(n-r)

P(2 Girls) = 3C2 * 0.5^2 * 0.5^1 =  3 * 0.25 * 0.5 = 0.375

P(1 boy | 2 Girls were born) = 1, as the total children are 3 and 2 are girls

P(2 Girls and 1 Boy) = P(2 Girls) * P(1 boy | 2 Girls were born)= 0.375 *1 = 0.375

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) is a mathjax guide to help you type maths.